# Скрипт в Таблице не видит функцию, пока не откроешь Редактор скриптов

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть Google-Таблица, созданная Владельцем.
Вледелец в ней открыл Редактор скриптов и создал скрипт "Код.gs".
Вледелец дал Программисту право Редактирования Таблицы.
Программист создал нужные функции и привязал их вызов на картинку (кнопку).

Проблема: при повторном открытии Google-Таблицы Программистом - "Функция не найдена". Возможно в это время другие пользователи пытались запускать скрипт и давали подтверждение на авторизацию.
Сейчас заходишь в редактор - выходишь и теперь работает запуск.

Как и где проверить права на запуск скрипта. Может быть право на запуск "всем пользователям" у которых есть доступ к Google-Таблице?

Comment: Если бы причина была в авторизации, сообщение об ошибке бы на это указало. Причина в другом.

Answer (score 1):

Назовем это: "инерция пользователя при работе в приложении с автосохранением".

Мы привыкли к тому, что приложения в браузере автоматически сохраняют введенные нами данные. Они следят за качеством ввода, уведомлениями и предупреждениями. Диск Google с его приложениями не исключиение за одним "но".

Но редактор Google Apps Script не сохраняет введенный код автоматически, зато оставляет предупреждения.

Пусть Bob и Alice работают в одном редакторе с одним файлом из-под своих учетных записей. Когда Bob ввел код, Alice его еще не видит, потому что Bob не нажал `CTRL+S`. Bob сохранил код, Alice его еще не видит, потому что Alice не обновила страницу браузера. Alice обновила страницу - видимая часть актуальна.  Назовем такое положение вещей - `"Состояние Ч"`.

Alice продолжает неистово жать `F5`, ожидая от Bob(а) все больше и больше актуального кода. Ок, `"Состояние Ч"` плавно движется во времени, и производная функции `состояния` по этому времени во всех точках имеет касательную.

Alice отвлеклась на некоторое время, которое позволило Bob(у) ввести и сохранить достаточно количество текста. Вернувшись, Alice потеряла свое неистовство в пользу практицизма, порядка и любопытсва. Она решила проверить, как работает код Bob(а). Она запустила скрипт, а порядочный и практичный редактор, необладающий явными признаками приложения, которое умеет автосохранять, его выполнил. Заметим, что выполнил правильно, без изъяна. А для пущей верности еще и сделал пуш всех последних изменений. Только чьих? Конечно Alice. Она пребывала в `"Состоянии Ч"`, в то время как Bob уже подготовил для этого состояния новое приращение. Вышеупомянутые касательные тут больше не появятся, тут не будет точки экстремума, тут... Тут фунция `"Сотояния Ч"` не существет?

Не совсем так, возможен излом. Но только, если Alice будет бдительной, сообщит об этом Bob(у), а Bob, не будь дураком, сохранит свое приращение поверх копии Alice. Если Bob в это время обновлял свою страницу или закрыл свою копию редактора, то его старания могут кануть в то место, где то самое "не существует" существует.

Правильно это или нет? По моему собственному убеждению, редактор косвенным образом мне показывает, что Bob - не имеет опыта работы с редактором, т.к. именно в его интересах было принять меры, а Alice ... Впрочем, если она платит, то ей можно.